# Interval of the $\arg{z}, z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis

The text book I'm reading that the main argument lies in the interval $[0,2\pi]$ or $[-\pi,\pi]$. The first one I understand geometrically. But the second one I do not. Where is the point $-\pi$ and which direction of rotation is the positive ?

Kind regards

Comment: $-\pi$ and $\pi$ both correspond to the point $(-1,0)$ on the unit circle. The positive direction of rotation, as usual, is anticlockwise.

Comment: The angle is defined modulo $2\pi$, so $-\pi$ is the same place as $\pi$, at the place of $-1$. By the way, we need one point to be excluded, otherwise this is not well-defined.

Comment: @rae306 What is not well defined?

Comment: An angle is defined modulo $2\pi$, so $0$ and $2\pi $ are the same angle. So you have to let $\text{Arg}:\mathbf{C}^\times\to [0,2\pi \color{red}{)}$.

Comment: Alright, thank you!